# How can I know if an instance of an AIR Application was invoked by the Installer?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

When you export a release build of an air app, it creates an .AIR file, that you can then double-click.  When you do so, it asks you if you want to "Add shortcut icon to my desktop" and "Start application after installation".

I need to call specific ActionScript within my AIR application if and only if it was launched by the installer (the 2nd checkbox was selected) - As opposed to the user re-running it from the start menu after having installed it.

How can I detect this within my program?

Answer (score 2):

With the `ApplicationUpdater` you can get the `isFirstRun` property that will return the [following](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdater.html#isFirstRun):

> Whether this is the first run after a successful update (true) or not
>   (false). The updater sets this value during the call to the
>   initialize() method.

Note that this will be true whenever you have pushed an update to your users. If you wan't your check to only return `true` the very first time the user opens your application (regardless of version number) you could write a file locally and check it's existence when the user opens your application. An example of how this could work can be found here:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/07/detecting-whether-an-air-application-has-run-before/